# How to send arralist on client by multithread server?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, server, client

I want to send arraylist on multithreading server to client . So far i just write the conection and the clients can write and send to server msg ,the server just send back the msg to client is write somathing just sending.  My main problems is how to transfer from server to client the arraylist ?
i am new on this and i dont know nothing for arralist .

code server :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

// Server class
class Server {


    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        private ArrayList<Objects> Obj = new ArrayList<Objects>();


        // file read 
     //   String filePath = "Hotels_new.txt";
    //    System.out.println(Read_File( filePath ));



        ServerSocket server = null;
  
        try {
  
            // server is listening on port 1234
            server = new ServerSocket(1234);
            server.setReuseAddress(true);
  
            // running infinite loop for getting
            // client request
            while (true) {
  
                // socket object to receive incoming client
                // requests
                Socket client = server.accept();
  
                // Displaying that new client is connected
                // to server
                System.out.println("New client connected" + client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
  
                // create a new thread object
                ClientHandler clientSock = new ClientHandler(client);
  
                // This thread will handle the client
                // separately
                new Thread(clientSock).start();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (server != null) {
                try {
                    server.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
  

    private static String Read_File(String filePath)
    {
 
        // Declaring object of StringBuilder class
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
 
        // try block to check for exceptions where
        // object of BufferedReader class us created
        // to read filepath
        try (BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                 new FileReader(filePath))) {
 
            String str;
 
            // Condition check via buffer.readLine() method
            // holding true upto that the while loop runs
            while ((str = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
 
                builder.append(str).append("\n");
            }
        }
 
        // Catch block to handle the exceptions
        catch (IOException e) {
 
            // Print the line number here exception occurred
            // using printStackTrace() method
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 
        // Returning a string
        return builder.toString();
    }



    // ClientHandler class
    private static class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
        private final Socket clientSocket;
  
        // Constructor
        public ClientHandler(Socket socket)
        {
            this.clientSocket = socket;
        }
  
        public void run()
        {
            PrintWriter out = null;
            BufferedReader in = null;
            try {
                    
                  // get the outputstream of client
                out = new PrintWriter( clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

                


                  // get the inputstream of client
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
  
                String line;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
  
                    // writing the received message from
                    // client
                    System.out.printf(" Sent from the client: %s\n",line);
                    out.println(line);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    if (out != null) {
                        out.close();
                    }
                    if (in != null) 
                    {
                        in.close();
                        clientSocket.close();
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

code client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
  
// Client class
class Client {
    
    // driver code
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // establish a connection by providing host and port
        // number
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234)) {
            
            // writing to server
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                socket.getOutputStream(), true);
  
            // reading from server
            BufferedReader in
                = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
  
            // object of scanner class
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String line = null;
  
           
            while (!"exit".equalsIgnoreCase(line)) {
                
                // reading from user
                line = sc.nextLine();
  
                // sending the user input to server
                out.println(line);
                out.flush();
  
                // displaying server reply
                System.out.println("Server replied "
                                   + in.readLine());
            }
            
            // closing the scanner object
            sc.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to send something more complex you will have to serialize it. You can choose how to do the serialization, maybe the easiest is to use `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` on the server and client respectively. These can be used very similarly to the `PrintWriter` / `BufferedReader` solution you are doing now.

I had to change a few things as your example code did not compile.

Example server based on your code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.List;

public class Server {
    private static final List<Integer> myIntArray = List.of(1, 2, 3);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket server = null;

        try {
            // server is listening on port 1234
            server = new ServerSocket(1234);
            server.setReuseAddress(true);

            // running infinite loop for getting
            // client request
            while (true) {
                // socket object to receive incoming client
                // requests
                Socket client = server.accept();

                // Displaying that new client is connected
                // to server
                System.out.println("New client connected" + client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());

                // create a new thread object
                ClientHandler clientSock = new ClientHandler(client);

                // This thread will handle the client
                // separately
                new Thread(clientSock).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (server != null) {
                try {
                    server.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // ClientHandler class
    private static class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
        private final Socket clientSocket;

        // Constructor
        public ClientHandler(Socket socket) {
            this.clientSocket = socket;
        }

        public void run() {
            try (ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()))) {

                while (in.readLine() != null) {
                    objectOutputStream.writeObject(myIntArray);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

// Client class
class Client {

    // driver code
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // establish a connection by providing host and port
        // number
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
             ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
             PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true)) {

            // object of scanner class
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String line = null;

            while (!"exit".equalsIgnoreCase(line)) {
                // reading from user
                line = sc.nextLine();

                // sending the user input to server
                out.println(line);
                out.flush();

                // displaying server reply
                List<Integer> integers = (List<Integer>) ois.readObject();

                System.out.println("server: " + integers.get(0));
            }

            // closing the scanner object
            sc.close();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that if you are about to send your own custom types, both sides will have to know about those to be able to serialize/deserialize. Also, your classes will have to be serializable.